# Is this a binomial or a hypergeometric distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

In the probability textbook that I am using, there is an example in the chapter on the binomial distribution:

> Suppose we are in one of those rare times when 65% of the American people approve of the way the President of the United States is handling his job. Take a random sample of $n=8$ Americans and let $Y$ equal the number who give approval. Then the distribution of $Y$ is $b(8,0.65)$.

The problem I have is that I am confused as to why $Y$ would have a binomial distribution. I think that the trials are not independent, that is, the probability of selecting a person who gives approval would be lower after already selecting another person. For example, suppose there are $10,000$ Americans, $5,000$ of whom give approval, and I select a person who happens to give approval. Then, the probability that I select another person who gives approval should be
$$\frac{4999}{9999}$$

A precondition of a binomial distribution is independent (Bernoulli) trials. This is why I believe $Y$ has a hypergeometric distribution. Is there something wrong with my understanding?

Comment: It is generally assumed, in problems like this, that the population is so large that one can safely treat the samples as independent.  That's why it is phrased in terms of a national population.  If you like, work it assuming a population of $10^4, 10^5, 10^6, 10^7$ and see how the answer changes...to confirm the validity of the approximation.

Comment: Worth noting:  if you are concerned about real world limitations on these sort of computations, keep in mind that the $65\%$ is (obviously) only approximate and sample dependent and the small sample of $8$ might well not be as "random" as the pollsters assure us it is.  There is a lot of noise in real polling problems, and I  think you'll find that worrying whether the population is $50$ million or $150$ million isn't really significant.

Comment: I see. So if I understand correctly, for a very large population and a small sample, the difference between prior and posterior probabilities are so small that they can be ignored, thus transforming the problem into one of binomial distribution (at least, for the sake of illustrating the binomial distribution). Thank you for your help!